# Python3 - SQLITE - Shows only one row

Tags: python, sqlite

this is my python code to get all tickets from a sqlite database, where the "IR" number is the same. When I run it and search a value, sqlite prints only one row, for the value "IR". But there are two rows in my database. This is my Database:
[Database content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jjli.png)

```
def seek(IR):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Test.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT IR FROM Tickets WHERE IR = ?"
    cur.execute(sql, (IR))
    fetch = cur.fetchall()
    print("Printing IR ", IR)
    print("Total rows are: ", len(fetch))
    for row in fetch:
        print("IR: ", row[0])
        print("Stellplatz: ", row[2])
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Which value is passed in where condition? you have just passed 'IR' in execute() but what is actual value of IR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue on my own. I forgot the "*" in the SQL Statment.